# Select rows that are referenced in another table

Tags: mysql, reference

I have two tables and they are as follows:

```
USERS
ORDERS
```

I want select all users who have at least 1 order or more in the ORDERS table. I know there is an inline query for this in MySQL, but right now I have to select all users and then make another query seeing if each user has an order - all this using a PHP loop.

What I am doing now is not ethically correct, so I basically just want to select all users who have been referenced in the ORDERS table in ONE MySQL query.

Comment: I think learning is a better option http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a query you should be using

```
select distinct u.* from users u
inner join orders o on o.user_id = u.id;
```

Note the `distinct` and `u.*`. This query will not select fields from `orders` and it will not select the same user twice (if one has more than one order).

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ebcc/3

Comment: This seems to work the best. How would I use count(*) in the selection if I don't want to return the array of users?

Comment: @user1998918: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.*) FROM ...`

Comment: are you missing group by ?

Comment: @IswantoSan: no, but it could also be used here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Any alternatives to `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.*) FROM` as that's just causing an error.

Comment: @Chris: obviously, this is an incomplete query. Substitute the rest from my answer. The fact that you weren't able to realize this, tells something about your experience with SQL. My advice to you: before you ask another sql question, go read a book on databases and sql.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Even in your fiddle, it doesn't work. I didn't post the entire query because I didn't want to clutter the comment box... Are you here to be sarcastic or what? I'd advise checking the fiddle you linked, replacing it with your solution and seeing for yourself.

Comment: @Chris: ah, I see now. Well, you should have posted the fiddle with demonstration. "Is giving me error" - this doesn't tell me anything. Try this: `select count(distinct u.id) from users u join items i on i.user_id = u.id;` The fiddle in the answer works for the original question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [mysql join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html%20join) syntax. Assuming both of your tables has userid column, this is the example :

```
SELECT * FROM USERS a JOIN ORDERS b ON
a.UserId = b.UserId
```

This is a simple database operation, see here for the explanation [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29%20join)

Comment: This query will select duplicate users if one has multiple orders. It will also select fields from orders.

Comment: awesome. thank you. if I am trying to select only one order (so I can count how many users have an order), how would I do that?

Comment: SELECT b.OrderId, COUNT(*) as UserOrderCount FROM USERS a JOIN ORDERS b ON
a.UserId = b.UserId GROUP BY b.OrderId